# Print significant digits in R

Tags: r, math, statistics, digit

I try to find a way to select a specific digit in a large number. 
For Example: number is `25896`, I want to define a new number which is second digit from right, so this number is `9`. Or I want to write second digit from left like `5`.

Comment: Perhaps `substr(str1, nchar(str1)-1, nchar(str1)-1)#[1] "9"` or `substr(str1, 2,2)#[1] "5"
`

Comment: You could probably cook something up with modulo (`%%`) as well.